# How do I render an SVG in an Android with react-native?

Tags: react-native

How render svg on android version app with react-native?
I find [react-native-svg](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-svg) but it only for IOS

Comment: react-native-svg now has good support for Android too.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it seems using a [`WebView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) is your only option for Android